# java script extract link from string

Tags: javascript, string

so I have this code on string:

```
<html class="
no - js ie ie6 lt - ie9 lt - ie8 lt - ie7 search - context en_US " lang="
en - US "> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="
no - js ie ie7 lt - ie9 lt - ie8 search - context en_US " lang="
en - US "> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="
no - js ie ie8 lt - ie9 search - context en_US " lang="
en - US "> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]>         <html class="
no - js ie9 search - context en_US " lang="
en - US "> <![endif]--><!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="
no - js search - context en_US " lang="
en - US "> <!--<![endif]-->    <head><title>art anime | Tumblr</title><!--[if ie]><meta http-equiv="
X - UA - Compatible " content="
IE = Edge, chrome = 1 "/><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="
Content - Type " content="
text / html;
charset = utf - 8 ">    <meta http-equiv="
x - dns - prefetch - control " content="
off ">    <meta name="
application - name " content="
Tumblr ">    <meta name="
msapplication - TileColor " content="
#3645d">    <meta name= "msapplication-TileImage"
content = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/msfavicon.png?_v=245323c5cb69e705ea213d9ed60e543a" > < link rel = "shortcut icon"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/favicons/favicon.ico?_v=8bfa6dd3e1249cd567350c606f8574dc"
type = "image/png" > < meta name = "p:domain_verify"
content = "d06c4fa470a9a6935c9a7b43d57eb7d2" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "57x57"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png?_v=81406f92242ce0166328bc17e4473e6e"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "60x60"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png?_v=20e3957f7027b72d5aa60085204ae63c"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "72x72"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png?_v=8df24181ba31066d8710f67c9a287241"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "76x76"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png?_v=455617cae13eff40acffac5e489bde50"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "120x120"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png?_v=5604f95b165810101ea055f2cb5206b9"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "128x128"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-128x128.png?_v=fd39307925fa7f1ada28b08d67e93da1"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "144x144"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png?_v=dfd5b392d423c5f0278d9f498abda2fa"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "152x152"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png?_v=73c2019bf6a75f7e476e01ba136cebec"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "180x180"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png?_v=00127c0342d97d5f36cfd8aa6439ca10"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "195x195"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-195x194.png?_v=0"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "196x196"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-196x196.png?_v=bb4b7eef0ef8e28101acdf2f0c265cc7"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "apple-touch-icon"
sizes = "228x228"
href = "https://assets.tumblr.com/images/apple-touch-icon-228x228.png?_v=0c7874da12e347c2bdf95e5baa3f396a"
type = "image/png" > < link rel = "canonical"
href = "https://www.tumblr.com/search/art%20anime/recent" > < meta name = "robots"
id = "robots"
content = "noodp,noydir" > < meta name = "description"
id = "description"
content = "Tumblr is a place to express yourself, discover yourself, and bond over the stuff you love. It&#039;s where your interests connect you with your people." > < meta name = "keywords"
id = "keywords"
content = "tumblelog, blog, tumblog, tumbler, tumblr, tlog, microblog" > < meta name = "viewport"
id = "viewport"
content = "width=960" > < meta name = "tumblr-form-key"
id = "tumblr_form_key"
content = "!1231553203788|mOZjoWSzPU6eNRkpuhEtzoBJmdA" > < meta name = "tumblr-gpop"
id = "tumblr_gpop"
content = "Tumblr" > < meta name = "og:title"
id = "og_title"
content = "art anime | Tumblr" > < meta name = "og:image"
id = "og_image"
content = "https://66.media.tumblr.com/06afadc2cafb6945065a4b10d61f3b45/tumblr_poqjiuUUGO1tvlw71o1_r1_500.jpg" > < script type = "application/ld+json" >
```

I want to get `content="https://66.media.tumblr.com ...` etc
link from this string and for you know the string is updating every hour

I try this way not working I result -1 and 0
on google script ( java script ) cods

```
function urll() { var response =
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.tumblr.com/search/art+anime/recent");
  var str = response.getContentText(); var m=str.search('is=“og_image”
  content=“(^”*)'); Logger.log(m); 
}
```

Comment: This is the exact string you want to parse?

Comment: yeah , how i exact ?

Comment: Well this 'string' doesn't look like a plain string - more like html - and not really usable as a string with all those " characters in it. Where do you get it from?

Comment: how you storing this sting content, it gives error when you put this in any variable,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jquery` to grab it. Per your example above, there is a unique `id` of `og_image`, so use that to get the `meta` element, then narrow it down to the `content` attribute.

```
$("meta #og_image").attr("content");
```

Assuming you already have that whole mess in a single variable myString:

```
var regex = /66\.[^"]*/;
var myLink = myString.match(regex);
```

myLink[0] will be the url.

To make this answer a bit more useful for other similar situations rather than just this niche case, if you're trying to pull a link out of a long string like this that contains many, you can use:

```
var regex = /http[^"]*/g;
var links = myString.match(regex);
```

That will give you an array of all the links.

```
links[links.length-1];
```

Will be the last one, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: but the problem this is cod is "string"

Comment: Added the javascript regex to parse out just the url from this "string" if you already have it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression like ‘is=“og_image” content=“(^”*)’ it will take every content url
If you need only last one, you can add the id parameter validation also

Comment: I don't know how add parameter validation, can you give example

Comment: I’ve updated my code. If you’ll need more details I can make the whole code sample later

Comment: jQuery sample will work - you just need to initialize the object with your string. Same way you use to create new html elements to be added to the page.